# Question about @ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathAndQuery()

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, e-commerce

i am following a book about creating a e-commerce website. I got to a part where i need to create the Default.cshtml for the Component. Here is the code.

```
@model GameSite.Data.Entities.Cart
<div class="">
    @if (Model.Lines.Count() > 0)
    {
        <small class="navbar-text">
            <b>Your cart:</b>
            @Model.Lines.Sum(x => x.Quantity) item(s)
            @Model.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("c")
        </small>
    }
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary navbar-btn" asp-page="/Cart"
       asp-route-returnurl="@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathAndQuery()">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

When i typed the code it said the following:

[PathAndQuery error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvvb6.png)

So i guess my question is there a replacement for the PathAndQuery.

Comment: It may help to know which book and exercise you are following; especially if there are published errata for the book.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request` returns a `HttpRequest`, which does not have the `PathAndQuery` method. However, it does have a `Url` method, returning a `Uri`, which has the `PathAndQuery` method. So `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery()` *might* work.